# Kayaking against the wind is faster than with wind in my back?

Tags: water, friction

Today I was kayaking on a lake. I noticed that there is not very strong, but noticeable wind. There were also currents, all going in one direction, probably caused by wind.

One more thing I realized was, that, surprisingly, I was able to paddle much easier and faster when I was going **against the currents**, thus wind, than when I had the wind in my back.

Is there any scientific explanation for this, or I have missed something else what influenced this phenomenon? If it is so, what could that be?

Comment: I am not sure if there is anything to this, and I cannot simply say that there isn't. But observations of speed on sea are really difficult, and the human eyes and ears are terrible comparison devices. https://twitter.com/neiltyson/status/276808419925712896 May I ask if you have made an actual measurement by kajaking a distance while measuring the time, or is the observation based on you eye-witness testimony alone?

Comment: Tides are not caused by wind, and if you were kayaking on a lake, then it is almost certain that whatever _currents_ you may have encountered, they were not _tides_.

Comment: @Steeven It didn't happen at sea, but rather lake. And I was fairly close to the coast. I did not make any measurement, however, so I may be wrong on this one.

Comment: @james large Sure, they were currents. I apologize for my poor English

Comment: I would also say that it's very difficult to estimate ground speed when you're in a boat. There are many false cues that can confuse your estimating faculties - the speed & direction of the wind, the speed & direction of water flow, the speed & direction of waves, etc. My guess would be that you weren't making a good estimation of your **ground speed**

Comment: Sounds like you were measuring your speed based on the ripples in the water. But since these move with the wind faster than the water underneath them, when going into the wind you get an *apparent* forward velocity that doesn't reflect your velocity with respect to the bulk water, or with respect to land.

Comment: @Chris White: it is the case then I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can have currents caused by something else that are pushing you one way while the wind is blowing the other.

Second, as the other answer says, the ripples from the wind can be deceiving. Far from the shore, it's difficult to get a sense of speed relative to trees or docks. And the ripples on the surface don't always extend into the water itself if the wind just started up. So the ripples can be moving while the bulk of the water you're pushing against is practically stationary.

According to [this page](http://www.kayakingworld.com.au/page15/page15.html), a typical kayak moves 2-3 knots, and winds up to around 10 knots aren't a big deal. Let's say the wind was blowing 3 knots and the ripples on top of the water were blowing 2 knots, and you were doing about 3 knots relative to the stationary water underneath.

Now, if you're heading into the wind, the ripples are moving towards you at 2 knots, and you towards them at 3 knots, for a total speed of 5 knots relative to the ripples. If you're heading away from the wind, you're going with the ripples, so your total speed relative to them is only 1 knot.

Of course, the wind is going to affect you a little, so maybe you're doing 2 knots into the wind and 4 knots the other way. Now your apparent speed is 4 knots against the wind and 2 knots with the wind. So it looks like you're doing twice the speed against the wind, but you're actually doing half the speed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't measure speed over the ground when you are moving in a boat unless you carefully observe nearby shore objects and measure your progress with a timepiece, or unless you have an instrument that measures speed against the bottom of the lake.

It's quite likely that you saw wind waves washing past you, and attributed their apparent speed to your boat's motion.  This is a misleading optical illusion.  There is no way that you can go faster against the wind and current than you can with the wind and current, unless you are paddling faster.

Answer (score 0):

I have timed a similar phenomenon swimming between two landmarks in the Corinth gulf in Greece and since then I have observed it in a small sea lake off it. It is due to currents below the surface, not caused by wind, but by water entering or leaving the gulf/sea lake. This in my case is a continuous flow one way or the other , due to the tides sometimes stronger or at the change still.

The volume of the lake is like a bowl, think of water entering with momentum on one side, it will be swirling , if it goes to the middle it will create swirls left and right when it hits the resistance ahead. This became very clear to me with the following funny observation:

A family of father mother and three kids came on two canoes and tied them up on a large red buoy in the deep waters of the lake, they wanted to swim a bit. The buoy though was one that had become dislodged and was floating with a large weight holding it upright, probably a frozen cement sac. At first , since there was a wind , the wind pushed the two tied up canoes, children and all, as if they were a sailboat and the buoy drifted with them. Then suddenly, the buoy started pulling the two canoes in the opposite direction, quite fast!!  They were mystified, untied and found a buoy where a boat was tied to have their swim. It was evident to me that an underlying strong current caught the buoy sac and was taking them for a ride.

So if your lake is fed by a river, or a river starts from it,  this is the explanation, underwater currents. If not, then it must be what the other answers say.

Comment: I thought this was the explanation, but I was on the other side of the lake and was moving perpendicularly. It must be that I have measured it wrong. Thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: on the other side of the lake to what? perpendicular to what? Is there a river flowin in or aout?  The currents follow contours of the sides and bottom and one would need a topology of the lake.

Comment: You could try an experiment with a buoy with a hanging weight that has some surface.